# Gitflow maven plugin stopped at release-start stage

Tags: git, maven, plugins

When i execute the `jgitflow:release-start` it will stuck at asking release name, what may be the reason for that?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jana 1.10-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m3:release-start (default-cli) @ jana ---
[INFO] ensuring origin exists...
[INFO] (develop) Checking for SNAPSHOT version in projects...
[INFO] (develop) Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
What is the release version for "jana"? (com.main.java:jana) [1.10]:
```

Answer (score 0):

It's asking you what you want the release version to be for your package. It's waiting for user input.